# Get repeat occurrences within dynamic time period

Tags: sql

Okay, here's the problem:  I've got a table with date stamped Transactions.  Suppose that the date is already removed from the date stamp and the table looks something like this:

```
;WITH TRX(TRX_Id, TRX_SalesTotal, TRX_TimeStamp) AS
    (
        SELECT  1, 100, '09:00:00' UNION ALL
        SELECT  2, 100, '09:10:00' UNION ALL
        SELECT  3, 200, '17:00:00' UNION ALL
        SELECT  4, 999, '11:50:00' UNION ALL
        SELECT  5, 999, '12:10:00' UNION ALL
        SELECT  6, 999, '12:15:00' UNION ALL
        SELECT  7, 100, '08:50:00' UNION ALL
        SELECT  8, 600, '17:00:00' UNION ALL
        SELECT  9, 700, '17:00:00' UNION ALL
        SELECT 10, 100, '09:45:00' UNION ALL
        SELECT 11, 100, '17:00:00' UNION ALL
        SELECT 12, 777, '09:00:00' UNION ALL
        SELECT 13, 777, '09:10:00' UNION ALL
        SELECT 14, 777, '10:10:00' 
    )
```

I must report on all transactions where the sales value occurs more than 2 times in an hour.  In any given hour.  (So one such period can be 12:30 - 13:30 for one sales total and 12:05 - 13:05 for another sales total, depending on the data.)

The result for the above data should therefore be:

```
TRX_ID   TRX_SalesTotal      TRX_TimeStamp
1        100                 09:00:00 
2        100                 09:10:00
7        100                 08:50:00
10       100                 09:45:00
4        999                 11:50:00
5        999                 12:10:00
6        999                 12:15:00
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TRX_Id, TRX_SalesTotal, TRX_TimeStamp
FROM TRX TRX1
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM TRX TRX2
       WHERE TRX1.TRX_SalesTotal=TRX2.TRX_SalesTotal
             AND
             TRX1.TRX_TimeStamp BETWEEN DATEADD(hour, -1, TRX2.TRX_TimeStamp)
                                        AND
                                        DATEADD(hour, 1, TRX2.TRX_TimeStamp))
       >1
```

See this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/37b9f/3)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick response.  Your solution looks at a two hour interval instead of 1 hour.  Note that transactions with ids 12, 13 and 14 should not be reported on.

Comment: You need to think a bit more about the problem. For a given transaction, you want to report it if at least one other is within an hour of it. I.e. 1 hour before and 1 hour after. The SQL fiddle is returning the result set you asked for.

Comment: No, it should only report on transactions where the sales value occurs more than TWO times in an hour.  (For my example I used two, but in the actual problem that will be a variable and will typically be much more)

Comment: @Ann did you look at the results of the SQL fiddle? It returns exactly the rows you have indicated 1,2,4,5,6,7 & 10.

Comment: I've added 3 rows to my original data to show you when it will not work.  (Also the query should specifically be > 2 and not > 1)

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you are after. Can you redraft your question to be more clear..